# PHP read everything until first comma

Tags: php

I have string that will look like this:

```
$string = "hello, my, name, is, az";
```

Now I just wanna echo whatever is there before first comma. I have been using following:

```
echo strstr($this->tags, ',', true);
```

and It has been working great, but the problem it only works php 5.3.0 and above. I am currently on PHP 5.2.

I know this could be achieve through regular express by pregmatch but I suck at RE.

Can someone help me with this.

Regards,

Comment: Why use a regular expression? Explode this into an array, and just echo the first element of the array.

Comment: `substr($string, 0, strpos($string, ','))`. don't use regexes (nuclear bomb) when a simple substring (water pistol) will work.

Comment: thank you @MarcB I was looking for something like that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<?php

$string = "hello, my, name, is, az";
echo substr($string, 0, strpos($string, ','));
```

You can (and should) add further checks to avoid substr if there's no `,` in the string.

Answer (score 6):

Use [**explode**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) than,

```
$arr = explode(',', $string,2);
echo $arr[0];
```

Comment: I like this argument better for its well commented and it uses all the properties of the explode function. Excelente answer @Rikesh

Answer (score 2):

You can explode this string using comma and read first argument of array like this

```
$string = "hello, my, name, is, az";
$str = explode(",", $string, 2);
echo $str[0];
```

Comment: +1, you're the first using the 3rd argument of explode, kudos!

Answer (score 1):

```
$parts = explode(',',$string);
echo $parts[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simple use the `explode` function:

```
$string = "hello, my, name, is, az";
$output = explode(",", $string);
echo $output[0];
```

Answer (score -1):

Too much explosives for a small work.

```
$str = current(explode(',', $string));
```